# Java NIO read large file from inputstream

Tags: java, nio

I want to read a large InputStream and return it as a file. So I need to split InputStream(or I should read InputStream in multiple threads). How can I do this? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
    URL url = new URL("path");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    int fileSize = connection.getContentLength();

    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    ReadableByteChannel rbc1 = Channels.newChannel(is);
    ReadableByteChannel rbc2 = Channels.newChannel(is);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("file.ext");

    FileChannel fileChannel1 = fos.getChannel();
    FileChannel fileChannel2 = fos.getChannel();
    fileChannel1.transferFrom(rbc1, 0, fileSize/2);
    fileChannel2.transferFrom(rbc2, fileSize/2, fileSize/2);

    fos.close();
```

But it does not affect on performance.

Comment: No, no, for goodness' sake NO!  streams are inherently sequential.  You cannot speed up their handling by trying to operate on them in parallel.  If you're lucky then you'll merely slow things down, but more likely you'll make a complete hash of the data.

Comment: Moreover, if the data are coming in over the network then your bottleneck is almost surely the network.  If not that, then it will be the local disk you are writing to.  It will not be data handling inside the receiving program when all you're doing is shuffling the bytes from source to sink.

Comment: The fundamental premiss is flawed. You can't read from two positions in a network stream at the same time. There is only one stream.

Comment: @JohnBollinger when TCP is used two streams over the same network can be faster than one (and it is debatable if this is unfair or not)

Comment: @eckes, sure, with *two streams*.  The OP has only *one* stream, and that's the situation he asked about.  It's unclear whether a two-stream arrangement for transferring his one file could even be arranged with the server.

Comment: "I want to read a large InputStream and return it as a file. So I need to split ..." *non sequitur.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open multiple (HTTP) Connections to the same resource (URL) but use the [`Range:` Header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) of HTTP to make each stream begin to read at another point. This can actually speed up the data transfer, especially when high latency is an issue. You should not overdo the parallelism, be aware that it puts additional load on the server.

```
connection1.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=0-" + half);
connection2.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + half+1 +"-");
```

This can also be used to resume downloads. It needs to be supported by the server. It can announce this with `Accept-Ranges: bytes`but does not have to . Be prepared that the first connection might return the whole requested entity (status 200 vs. 206) instead.

You need to read the input streams from the URLConnections in separate threads as this is blocking IO (not sure if the NIO wrapping helps here).

Answer (score -1):

You can use position(long) method for each channel to start reading for.

Check this.

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/file-channel.html#filechannel-position

Besides, if you want download a file partially,

> Parallel Downloading
>
> To download multiple parts of a file parallelly, we need to create
>   multiple threads. Each thread is implemented similarly to the simple
>   thread above, except that it needs to download only a part of the
>   downloaded file. To do that, the HttpURLConnection or its super class
>   URLConnection provides us method setRequestProperty to set the range
>   of the bytes we want to download.
>
> ```
> // open Http connection to URL
> HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)mURL.openConnection();
>
> // set the range of byte to download
> String byteRange = mStartByte + "-" + mEndByte;
> conn.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + byteRange);
>
> // connect to server
> conn.connect();
> ```

This would be helpful for you.

I found this answer here, you can check complete tutorial.

http://luugiathuy.com/2011/03/download-manager-java/

Comment: All that will do is read data from the network, taking just as much time as, err, reading the data. The fundamental premiss is flawed. You can't read from two positions in a network stream at the same time. See @JohnBollinger's comments above.

Comment: Sometimes I don't get why NO answers tries to cover the word. This guy wants an answers for parallel downloading. What you serve is just saying NO. Please be motivating for seeking answer people.

Comment: Commenting is not showing effect ? Sorry but you gotta be more supportive.

Comment: I don't know what 'commenting is not showing effect?' is supposed to mean, or where exactly it says I "gotta be more supportive'. You can't support an idea that doesn't make sense.